# what would be in preferred approach to plotting data?

Tags: python, python-3.x

let us assume I have several datasets whose plots I want to compare. One approach would be:

```
 paths = ['list', 'of', 'folders']
 colors = ['r', 'g', 'b'] # list of colors based on number of folders

 for i, path in enumerate(paths):
    sn = create_object_holding_data(path)
    sn.load_data()
    sn.plot_currents()
    sn.plot_density()
    sn.plot_temperature()
```

the other approach would be

```
 sn_list=[]
 for i, path in enumerate(paths):
      sn = create_object_holding_data(path)
      sn.load_data()
      sn_list.append(sn)

 compare_currents(sn_list)
 compare_temperatures(sn_list)
 compare_densities(sn_list)
```

In the first case, all data is being loaded sequentially. In the other one all data is being loaded at once. In the particular problem at hand, the amount of data is not particularly large. What is the preferred approach in cases like this? what kind of trouble should one look for in both these cases? My goal is to prevent rewriting code while being clear to myself as what I am doing.

Comment: I don't understand how you compare data in the first approach. You just call plot but you don;t compare anything, since the previous data is not yet loaded. It looks like this two codes do different things. If you want to compare things, you need all this things loaded when you compare them, otherwise you cannot do any comparison.

Comment: @Elerium115, in the first approach, you load one set of data, plot it. Keep the figure available and plot over it again the next time in the loop. I wanted to ask about how to approach this without presenting confusing details.

Comment: ah, so you are plotting multiple plots on the same figure, you are not comparing plots. Then the second approach loads first all the data and then plots it?

Comment: @Elerium115, the currents on one figures, densities on another and so on ...

Comment: Why use `enumerate` when you make no use of the count value `i` ?

Comment: @user19077881, one of the things I omitted to make the pseudocode simple. Here,  enumerate is used in the first example to choose a unique color within the loop